# Using Highcharts.js to create a punch card style graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to replicate the "punch-card" style graph presented on github via highcharts.

[image: GitHub Punch Card Graph]

I'm really struggling with this one, here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CA2cT/1/) that starts to get me there.  I'd rather have days on the y and time on the x, but I'm at a loss at to how I should go about doing this.

Any help appreciated.

TIA!

Comment: Updated jsfiddle with a modification of mangobug's suggestion.  All that's left is to get time on the y-axis.

Comment: Here's another update that gets the y and x axis labels how you want:  http://jsfiddle.net/CA2cT/8/

Comment: Perfect finish!  Thanks for dragging that across the line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was not able to flip the axis but sorted out a lot of things for you.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    defaultSeriesType: 'scatter'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},
yAxis: {

},
plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
        marker: {
            radius: 4,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true,
                    lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                }
            }
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    data: [{y: 161}, {y: 167}, {y: 165}, {y: 140}, {y: 172}, {y: 163}, {y: 187}, {y: 107}, {y: 147}, {y: 145}, {y: 112}, {y: 199}]
}]
});
```

Comment: Super close - much appreciated.  If I could figure out how to display hours 00:00 through 24:00 on the y-axis then this would be a winner.  I updated the fiddle to display Sun-Sat on x-axis.  Thanks for getting me closer.

Comment: I'm glad I was of help, though an up vote would have been really encouraging :P **kidding**. Would try to look into for further improvement.

Answer (score 5):

I guess it's to late now but maybe this solution will help other people in the same situation.

Here is my solution:

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      defaultSeriesType: 'scatter'
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Punchcard'
    },

    xAxis: {
      type: "datetime",
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        hour: '%I %P'  
      },
      tickInterval: 3600000 * 1
    },

    yAxis: {
      categories: ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'],
    },

    series: [{
      data: [

        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 1,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }}, 
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 2,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 3,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 4,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 5,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 6,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 7,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 8,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 9,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 10, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 11, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 12, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 13, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 14, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 15, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 16, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 17, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 18, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 19, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 20, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 21, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 22, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 0, x: 3600000 * 23, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},

        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 1,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }}, 
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 2,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 3,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 4,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 5,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 6,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 7,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 8,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 9,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 10, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 11, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 12, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 13, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 14, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 15, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 16, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 17, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 18, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 19, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 20, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 21, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 22, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 1, x: 3600000 * 23, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},

        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 1,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }}, 
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 2,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 3,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 4,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 5,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 6,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 7,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 8,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 9,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 10, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 11, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 12, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 13, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 14, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 15, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 16, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 17, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 18, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 19, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 20, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 21, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 22, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 2, x: 3600000 * 23, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},

        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 1,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }}, 
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 2,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 3,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 4,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 5,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 6,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 7,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 8,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 9,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 10, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 11, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 12, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 13, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 14, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 15, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 16, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 17, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 18, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 19, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 20, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 21, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 22, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 3, x: 3600000 * 23, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},

        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 1,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }}, 
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 2,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 3,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 4,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 5,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 6,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 7,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 8,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 9,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 10, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 11, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 12, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 13, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 14, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 15, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 16, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 17, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 18, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 19, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 20, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 21, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 22, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 4, x: 3600000 * 23, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},

        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 1,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }}, 
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 2,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 3,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 4,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 5,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 6,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 7,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 8,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 9,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 10, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 11, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 12, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 13, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 14, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 15, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 16, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 17, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 18, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 19, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 20, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 21, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 22, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 5, x: 3600000 * 23, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},

        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 1,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }}, 
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 2,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 3,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 4,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 5,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 6,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 7,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 8,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 9,  marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 10, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 11, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 12, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 13, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 14, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 15, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 16, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 17, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 18, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 19, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 20, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 21, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 22, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},
        {y: 6, x: 3600000 * 23, marker: { radius: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }},

      ]
    }]

  });

});
```

And here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KmPJE/1/

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: No problem! I'm currently working on a better approach using the bubble charts instead of scatter.

Answer (score 2):

I [updated the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CA2cT/6/) from @mangobug to guide you to a closer way of doing what you want

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined`